# Angular Material Dropdown Menu Not Triggering Correctly with Dynamic Content

Tags: angular

[image]

I am currently working on an Angular project with Angular Material components, and I am facing an issue with my dropdown menu implementation. The buttons in my dropdown are not triggering as expected. I would appreciate some guidance or insights on what might be causing this problem.

<

```
div class="category">
        <div class="btn-group" *ngFor="let category of productCategory;let i=index">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default list" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #triggerMenu="matMenuTrigger" (mouseenter)="categoryList(i);triggerMenu.openMenu()">
                <span>{{category}}</span>
            </button>
            
            <mat-menu [hasBackdrop]="false" #menu="matMenu" class="menu">
                <span (mouseleave)="triggerMenu.closeMenu()">
                    <button *ngFor="let index of list;let i=index;" mat-menu-item class="list" (click)="categoryProduct(index.request,index.category);setCategoryClicked(true)">{{index.category}}</button>
                </span>
            </mat-menu>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

The issue is that the dropdown menus aren't triggering as expected. The menus are supposed to open on mouse enter and populate based on the category selected, but this isn't happening consistently. I suspect it could be a problem with how I'm binding matMenuTriggerFor or perhaps an issue with the dynamic content. I'm looking for suggestions on how to debug this issue or any insights into what might be going wrong. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I want the menu item show according to the category hovered